# How can I convert a json string into a javascript array

Tags: json

I'm getting a `json` string that looks like this:

```
[{"id":1,"class_code":1,"first_name":"Barry","last_name":"Allen","grade":null,"behavior":1,"beh_comments":null,"random_seating":null,"ascending_seats":null,"descending_seats":null},{"id":2,"class_code":1,"first_name":"Bruce","last_name":"Banner","grade":null,"behavior":2,"beh_comments":null,"random_seating":null,"ascending_seats":null,"descending_seats":null}
```

I need to turn this to a `javascript` array. This code:

```
var arr = Object.keys(jsonRoster).map(function (key) {return jsonRoster[key]});
```

gives me each individual character `("b","a","r","r","y")` but I wish to access the whole "barry".

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse method to get array and then can access the first name or last name as per need, if that is what you are trying to do.

```
var j = '[{"id":1,"class_code":1,"first_name":"Barry","last_name":"Allen","grade":null,"behavior":1,"beh_comments":null,"random_seating":null,"ascending_seats":null,"descending_seats":null},{"id":2,"class_code":1,"first_name":"Bruce","last_name":"Banner","grade":null,"behavior":2,"beh_comments":null,"random_seating":null,"ascending_seats":null,"descending_seats":null}]';

var arr = JSON.parse(j)
```

And then you can use something like :

```
 arr[0].first_name
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Good to know. Please accept it as answer in that case.